# A static void method named randTest that takes a single integer argument, n

Tags: java, for-loop, count, int, increment

I am having trouble with figuring out this piece of code, in the randTest method i must declare an int array of 10 elements named counts. This will be used to record how often each possible value is returned by randInt which is a static int method i created that generates a random integer.

I must Call randInt n times, each time incrementing the count of the element of counts corresponding to the value returned.

This is the code i have produced so far for the randTest method:

```
    public static void randTest(int n){

    int [] counts = new int [10];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        counts[i] = RandInt();
        System.out.println(counts[i]);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` change to `for(int i=0;i<n;i++)`

Comment: You're not doing what you're being asked. What you're being asked to do is call randInt() N times (and not 10). Each time you call it, if it returns 6 (for example), you must increment `counts[6]`. That way, in the end, if you want to know how many times 4 was generated, you can look it up in `counts[4]`. That should be enough to help you figure out by yourself how to change the code.

Comment: You should read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) probably

Comment: So, what is the result you're getting with this piece of code?

Also, you may want to use condensed for method when you're dealing with arrays (for the sake of convenience).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

I presume, you have limited the result of randTest() to integers from 0 to 9. Just to be shure, I have added the IllegalArgumentException.

```
public static void randTest(int n) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if ((n < 0 ) || (n > 9)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only values between 0 and 9 are accepted.");
    }

    int [] counts = new int [10];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int rInt = RandInt();
        counts[rInt]++;
        System.out.println("Integer of value " + rInt + " was called " 
                            + counts[rInt] + " times so far.");
    } 
}
```